# Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: toastrProvider <- toastr <- toaster

Tags: angularjs, typescript, toastr

I have an Angular service built in TypeScript that injects toastr as a dependency and I get the following error:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: toastrProvider <- toastr <- toaster
```

Here is the service:

```
module app {
    'use strict';        

    export interface IToasterService {
        toastrDefaults(): ToastrOptions;
        success: (text: string, title?: string, optionsOverride?) => void;
        info: (text: string, title?: string, optionsOverride?) => void;
        warning: (text: string, title?: string, optionsOverride?) => void;
        error: (text: string, title?: string, optionsOverride?) => void;
    }

    export class ToasterService implements IToasterService {

        static $inject: Array<string> = ['toastr'];
        constructor(private toastr: Toastr) {
        }

        toastrDefaults(): ToastrOptions {
            var toastrOptions: ToastrOptions = {
                timeOut: 2000,
                extendedTimeOut: 1000,
                positionClass: "toast-top-right-content"
            };

            return toastrOptions;
        }

        success(text, title, optionsOverride) {
            this.toastrDefaults();
            this.toastr.success(text, title, optionsOverride);
        }

        info(text, title, optionsOverride) {
            this.toastrDefaults();
            this.toastr.info(text, title, optionsOverride);
        }

        warning(text, title, optionsOverride) {
            this.toastrDefaults();
            this.toastr.warning(text, title, optionsOverride);
        }

        error(text, title, optionsOverride) {
            this.toastrDefaults();
            this.toastr.error(text, title, optionsOverride);
        }
    }

    angular.module('app').service('toaster', ToasterService);
}
```

I have tried a number of different solutions. Nothing has worked so far. Any ideas?

Comment: Where does that toastr service come from? Have you declared its module as a dependency of your application module? Sorry for the close vote BTW. I read the question too fast and thought you had a typo between toastr and toaster.

Comment: It is not declared as a dependency on the application module. It did not need to be declared on the application module prior converting it to TypeScript.

Comment: Also, toastr is an external module. I brought in both toastr and the typing file from nuget.

Answer (score 0):

Frustratingly enough, this issue has been nagging me for at least a month and I may have solved it, though I am not sure how correct it is. I am going to leave this answer here for others to comment on in case there are any ramifications for this fix.

```
module app {
    'use strict';        

    export interface IToasterService {
        toastrDefaults(): ToastrOptions;
        success: (text: string, title?: string, optionsOverride?) => void;
        info: (text: string, title?: string, optionsOverride?) => void;
        warning: (text: string, title?: string, optionsOverride?) => void;
        error: (text: string, title?: string, optionsOverride?) => void;
    }

    export class ToasterService implements IToasterService {

        constructor() {
        }

        toastrDefaults(): ToastrOptions {
            var toastrOptions: ToastrOptions = {
                timeOut: 2000,
                extendedTimeOut: 1000,
                positionClass: "toast-top-right-content"
            };

            return toastrOptions;
        }

        success(text, title, optionsOverride) {
            toastrDefaults();
            toastr.success(text, title, optionsOverride);
        }

        info(text, title, optionsOverride) {
            toastrDefaults();
            toastr.info(text, title, optionsOverride);
        }

        warning(text, title, optionsOverride) {
            toastrDefaults();
            toastr.warning(text, title, optionsOverride);
        }

        error(text, title, optionsOverride) {
            toastrDefaults();
            toastr.error(text, title, optionsOverride);
        }
    }

    angular.module('app').service('toaster', ToasterService);
}
```

I removed the injection altogether. Now, this works. But is it correct?

Answer (score 0):

Another Approach:  First inject the raw toastr.js into a value service using the type of Toastr.  Then inject the value service into a custom NotifierService. This fixes the provider error because a value service is a provider.  Don't know if this approach is an improvement though. The idea of injecting toastr.js into a value service first came from a non type script PluralSight video by Joe Eames on the Mean Stack.

`

```
((): void => {
    'use strict';
    let toasterService: Toastr;

    angular.module('app.common')
        .value('toastrService', toastr);
})();

namespace App.Common {
    'use strict';

    export interface INotifier {
        success(message: string): void;
        error(message: string): void;
        warning(message: string): void;
    }

    export class Notifier implements INotifier {
        static $inject = ['toastrService'];
        constructor(private toastrService: Toastr) {
            this.toastrService.options =
            {
                showDuration: 300,
                timeOut: 2000,
                toastClass: 'toast-top-right'

            }as ToastrOptions;
        }

        success(message: string): void {
            this.toastrService.success(message); 
        }

        error(message: string): void {
            this.toastrService.error(message);
        }

        warning(message: string): void {
            this.toastrService.warning(message);
        }
    }

    angular
        .module('app.common')
        .service('App.Common.Notifier', Notifier);
}
```

`